# How to return nothing from many-to-many if right side contains something specific?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a many-to-many mapped via an ORM. I select from the left table and use 2 left outer joins to pull in the right table.

Everything works fine, but I have a case where if the right table contains a specific value, then the query should return nothing.

Here is a contrived, simplified example:

```
 people          people_fruits          fruits
id | name     people_id | fruit_id     id | name
---------------------------------------------------
 1 | Tom              1 | 1             1 | apple
 2 | Paul             1 | 2             2 | banana
 3 | Kim              2 | 1             3 | orange
                      2 | 3
```

A given query might look like:

```
SELECT p.*, f.*
FROM people AS p
         LEFT OUTER JOIN people_fruits AS pf ON pf.people_id = p.id
         LEFT OUTER JOIN fruits AS f ON pf.fruits_id=f.id
WHERE p.id = 1;
```

Pretty standard. But let's say I want to pretend people associated with oranges simply don't exist (sorry orange fans). I want the following query to return an empty set:

```
SELECT p.*, f.*
FROM people AS p
         LEFT OUTER JOIN people_fruits AS pf ON pf.people_id = p.id
         LEFT OUTER JOIN fruits AS f ON pf.fruits_id=f.id
WHERE p.id = 2;
```

This query should return an empty set.

Queries for `Tom` and `Kim` should return results, but queries for `Paul` should not.

How can such a query be written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` or `NOT IN` as following. `NOT IN` must be used carefully as it needs to handle null condition along with it.

```
-- NOT EXISTS --
SELECT p.*, f.*
FROM people AS p
LEFT JOIN people_fruits AS pf ON pf.people_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN fruits AS f ON pf.fruits_id = f.id

-- added this where condition with not exists
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
FROM people_fruits PFIN JOIN fruits FIN
ON PFIN.fruits_id = FIN.id
AND FIN.NAME = 'orange'
and PFIN.people_id = p.id);



-- NOT IN --
SELECT p.*, f.*
FROM people AS p
LEFT JOIN people_fruits AS pf ON pf.people_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN fruits AS f ON pf.fruits_id = f.id

-- added this where condition with not IN
WHERE p.id not in (SELECT PFIN.people_id
FROM people_fruits PFIN JOIN fruits FIN
ON PFIN.fruits_id = FIN.id
AND FIN.NAME = 'orange');
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to aggregate by person and assert that he is never associated with oranges:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT p.id
    FROM people AS p
    LEFT JOIN people_fruits AS pf ON pf.people_id = p.id
    LEFT JOIN fruits AS f ON pf.fruits_id = f.id
    GROUP BY p.id
    HAVING COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE f.name = 'orange') = 0
)

SELECT p.*, f.*
FROM people AS p
LEFT JOIN people_fruits AS pf ON pf.people_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN fruits AS f ON pf.fruits_id = f.id
WHERE p.id IN (SELECT id FROM cte);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works! I'm checking the other answer as correct simply because it fits into an ORM fragment a bit easier than the code you have provided. Cheers!